# ssh-keyscan fails for ipv6 addresses

Tags: ssh, ipv6

I can't get ssh-keyscan to work for ipv6 addresses.  Can someone help me?

```
$ ssh-keyscan -6v -t rsa FE80:0000:021B:21FF:FEDA:62AD
getaddrinfo FE80:0000:021B:21FF:FEDA:62AD: Name or service not known

$ ssh-keyscan -6v -t rsa [FE80:0000:021B:21FF:FEDA:62AD]
getaddrinfo [FE80:0000:021B:21FF:FEDA:62AD]: Name or service not known
```

but this works:

```
$ ping6 -I bond0  fe80::21b:21ff:feda:62ad
PING fe80::21b:21ff:feda:62ad(fe80::21b:21ff:feda:62ad) from fe80::21b:21ff:feda:64a9 bond0: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::21b:21ff:feda:62ad: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.571 ms
64 bytes from fe80::21b:21ff:feda:62ad: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.165 ms
64 bytes from fe80::21b:21ff:feda:62ad: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.145 ms
^C
--- fe80::21b:21ff:feda:62ad ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2206ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.145/0.293/0.571/0.197 ms
```

Comment: Post the output of `ssh-keyscan -6v -t rsa fe80::21b:21ff:feda:62ad%bond0`

Comment: $ ssh-keyscan -6v -t rsa fe80::21b:21ff:feda:62ad%bond0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
# fe80::21b:21ff:feda:62ad%bond0 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
fe80::21b:21ff:feda:62ad%bond0 ssh-rsa AAAAB

Comment: Sorry for the above mess, too many characters to post.  But you can see that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified a link-local IPv6 address but forgot the scope. Add the scope ID to it.

You also are missing some octets in the address as you originally gave it.

Correct both of these problems:

```
ssh-keyscan -6v -t rsa FE80::021B:21FF:FEDA:62AD%bond0
```

Comment: Thank you Michael.  That works.   Can you explain the comment about missing octets?  I think they are all there.  There are 6 of them.  But I think a bigger question is about how scope plays in to ipv6.  Can you explain how these work together?  I have not yet found a good explanation of ipv6, what scope is about, and exactly what that means to the usual linux files, such as /etc/hosts.  Thank you.

Comment: I would also like to add there is nothing in the man page for ssh-keyscan  which says I should add "%<interface name>" to the ipv6 address.  How did you know what is the proper format?

Comment: It wouldn't be in the ssh-keyscan man page. No more than the format of IPv4 addresses would be. This is standard for IPv6 link local addresses; see the relevant RFCs.

Comment: See also [Why is there a percent sign '%' in the IPv6 address?](http://superuser.com/q/99746/144961)

Comment: @fbat It is not the job of the ssh-keyscan man page to teach you how to properly use IPv6 addresses.